# Select rows with same ID, collapse rows with null / non-null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I feel like as soon as I see this I'm going to smack myself but here goes:

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE testdata (
    id int,
    email varchar(25),
    street nvarchar(50),
    town nvarchar(15),
    zip nvarchar(5)
    source nvarchar(15))


INSERT INTO testdata (
    id,
    email,
    street,
    town,
    zip,
    source
)
VALUES
    (
        1,
        'myemail@email.com',
        null,
        'happy',
        null
    ),
    (
        1,
        'myemail@gmail.com',
        null,
        'happy',
        '19400'
    );
```

This yields:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
|id |email              |street        |town        |zip    |
|1  |myemail@email.com  |happy place   |happy       |(null) |
|1  |myemail@gmail.com  |(null)        |happy       |19400  |
```

What I'm trying to arrive at is

```
|id |email              |street        |town        |zip    |
|1  |myemail@email.com  |happy place   |happy       |19400  |
```

Basically I want to collapse all the rows and grab anything that is not null where the ID is the same.  If they are both null, then grab the null values.  I attempted a self-join with a coalesce however that didn't work.  I feel as if I'm close however is there a function out there that I can use that would make this easier?

Caveats:  There can only be two rows with the same ID(Not sure if this makes it harder or easier).  And If both rows are populated with information, I would want the first row.

Comment: What does "first row" mean to you? Consider that, to SQL Server, a table is an unsorted bag of rows, unless you have some data in the table that defines what order means to you. Also a column called `id` but that allows duplicate values seems like a serious design flaw. An identifier should be a key.

Comment: If you make `id` a primary key and `email` a unique constraint, you will never get duplicates.

Comment: It's a bit to get into but essentially having the same ID is by nature of another process which collapses the records.  So, in the above case, it was ID 1 and ID 2 at one point however the system identified the duplicate values and thus deleted one and kept another. This is the 50,000 foot view

Comment: If a user has entered its credentials twice, you should probably take the last in time. If he moved to another place, then it's probably not a good idea to fill in the missing parts from another entry, as this could mix up unrelated addresses. If he moves from "Tiny Village" without street names to Broadway, New York, the result might become Broadway, Tiny Village.

Comment: Sadly this is driven by a sales team.  When someone is too lazy to search for person X, they simply input him in which generates a new unique ID.  Since all the other information could be matched, it gets collapsed via a process within the CRM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "first" row in a table, unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.  Your table does not have such a column.

So, the best that you can do is aggregation:

```
select email, max(street) as street, max(town) as town, max(zip) as zip
from testdata
group by email;
```

Comment: If the OP wants the first row, and town is `sad` in the second row, this will return town from the second row.

Comment: This s actually as good as it's going to get unfortunately. The positive is that it's only about 20k rows a month out of 50mil+